# Applying CellStyle on agGrid instantly whenever CellValueChanged

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using agGrid in Angular.

I need to set background color of cell to yellow when cell value changed and background color to red when someone edit to make the value empty.

Here's the code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { APICallService } from '../../.././PortalServices/webapicall.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'master-gender',
    templateUrl: 'app/PortalPages/MasterPages/GenderMaster/gender.component.html',
    providers: [APICallService],
})

export class GenderComponent implements OnInit {
    private updateDict = new Map();
    genderRowData: [];  

    constructor(private genderService: APICallService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.genderService.getApiCall('getallgenders')
            .subscribe((rowData) => this.genderRowData = rowData,
                (error) => { alert(error) }
            );   
    }

    columnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: 'Gender Name', field: 'Name',                                          
            onCellValueChanged: this.genderCellValueChanged.bind(this)           
        },
    ]

    genderCellValueChanged(event: any) {
        const cell = event.api.getFocusedCell();
        if (event.oldValue !== event.newValue) {
            if (event.newValue == '')
              cell.column.colDef.cellStyle = { 'background-color': 'red' }; 
            else
               cell.column.colDef.cellStyle = { 'background-color': 'yellow' }; 
         }
         event.api.refreshCells(cell);     
    }
}
```

The cellStyle never applied when cell value changed for first time. However when I try to edit the cell for second time then cellStyle applied. I tried to use redrawRows() but it is affecting whole column which I dont want. I want to change the style of cell whenever value is getting changed.

How to refresh the style instantly?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide it within `ColDef`.

Reference: [ag-grid - Cell style](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/#cell-style)

```
columnDefs = [{
  name: 'Gender Name',
  field: 'Name',
  cellStyle: function(params) {
    if (params.value =='') {
        return { backgroundColor: 'red' };
    } else {
        return { backgroundColor: 'yellow' };
    }
  }
},
// your other colDefs
]
```

When you mark the field as editable and when the value gets updated, the color will get changed.

Comment: This is not working in my case. I have couple of more headers in agGrid so I put colDef in array.Can you please give working example?

Comment: There was some type in the code I provided, updated it. Its pretty straight-forward. Can you give me plunk or stackblitz reproducing the issues?

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the answer to my question. Hope this answer will help those who wanted to acheive the same functionality.

Refresh of cell is done forcefully. Below function is modified:-

```
genderCellValueChanged(event: any) {
        const cell = event.api.getFocusedCell();
        if (event.oldValue !== event.newValue) {
            if (event.newValue == '')
              cell.column.colDef.cellStyle = { 'background-color': 'red' }; 
            else
               cell.column.colDef.cellStyle = { 'background-color': 'yellow' }; 
         }
         let refreshParams = {
            force: true,
            rowNodes: [event.node]
        };
        event.api.refreshCells(refreshParams);   
    }
```

Comment: Using the api provided by ag-grid would be simpler. Instead of calling `api.refreshCell`, using `cellStyle` would be more convenient.

Comment: This approach could impact of performance in such of cases, cuz update made out of ag-grid scope and then calling update with API `refreshCells`, as @Paritosh mentioned, better to define `cellStyle` property with required logic.

Comment: But cellStyle property do not have event.newValue by which I can understand that value in the cell has been changed. Is there way to do so?

Comment: @simpleuser its automatically tracked check [here](http://www.ag-grid.co.uk/example.php#/) change the value on any coloured cell and you will see the result, also if you need to show changes check [here](http://www.ag-grid.co.uk/javascript-grid-charts-overview/#example-application-created-charts) `cellRenderer:'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer'`